# What is `Go http package`?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I was looking through my apache logs trying to debug something, and I noticed the following in my logs:

> IP removed1 - - [17/Oct/2011:08:58:51 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1506 "-" "Go http package"
>
> IP removed2 - - [17/Oct/2011:08:58:51 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1506 "-" "Go http package"
>
> IP removed1 - - [17/Oct/2011:08:58:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1506 "-" "Go http package"
>
> IP removed3 - - [17/Oct/2011:09:02:52 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1506 "-" "Go http package"
>
> IP removed1 - - [17/Oct/2011:09:02:53 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1506 "-" "Go http package"
>
> IP removed3 - - [17/Oct/2011:09:02:54 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1506 "-" "Go http package"

What is it? All it ever does is a `GET  /`, so should I be concerned?

Also, as you can see by `IP removed*`, I noticed three separate IP addresses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears to be a user agent for requests made by [Go](http://golang.org/), one of Google's programming languages. It looks like someone may be trying to script requests to your site.

Comment: There were three different IPs - probably should have mentioned that.